# Creating an option select from db using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

I am trying to create an additional form text field on click of a button which wotrtks fine, my only problem is that the select option is blank and when I inspect element I see that NAN is added to it.
Here is the design for the dynamic form elements container

```
      <div class="col-sm-6" id="prescription-container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="drug" class="form-label">Medicine </label>
                                        <select name="drug[]" class="form-control search-select">
                                            <?php echo $drug_drop_down; ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Comment</label>
                                        <div class="phone-icon">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="diagnosis">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="#" id="add_prescription" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add
                                prescription</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is how I have implemented the onclick listener for the add prescription button

```
       <script>
    $("#add_prescription").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var result="<option value=''>Select Drug<option>";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'drugs',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        result += "<option value='" + data.id + "'>"+data.name+"<option>";
                    })
                } else{
                    result += "<option value='" + data.id + "'>"+data.name+"<option>";
                }
                $('#prescription-container').append(" <div class='row'> <div class='col-md-6'>" +
                    "<div class='form-group'>" +
                    "<label for='drug' class='form-label'>Medicine </label><select name='drug[]'' class='form-control'>" +
                    + result +
                    "</select>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class='col-sm-6'>" +
                    "<div class='form-group'>" +
                    "<label>Comment</label>" +
                    "<div class='phone-icon'>" +
                    "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='diagnosis'>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>")
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Finally this is the controller sending back data

```
       function () {
    $drugs = Medicine::get();
    return response()->json( $drugs);
}
```

Now my problem is that when i alert(data) I get [object Object],[object Object]. This made me modify the controller as follows

```
       function () {
    $drugs = Medicine::get();
    $drug_drop_down = "<option>Select drug</option>";
    foreach($drugs as $drug){
        $drug_drop_down .="<option value='".$drug->id."'>$drug->name</option>";
    }
    return response()->json( $drug_drop_down);
}
```

and the onclick listener to

```
      <script>
    $("#add_prescription").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'drugs',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#prescription-container').append(" <div class='row'> <div class='col-md-6'>" +
                    "<div class='form-group'>" +
                    "<label for='drug' class='form-label'>Medicine </label><select name='drug[]'' class='form-control'>" +
                    + data +
                    "</select>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class='col-sm-6'>" +
                    "<div class='form-group'>" +
                    "<label>Comment</label>" +
                    "<div class='phone-icon'>" +
                    "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='diagnosis'>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>")
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Now if I  `alert(data)` I get `<option>Select drug</option><option value='1'>Quinine</option><option value='2'>Malariaquine</option>` but the select is still being added without options and the following appear on inspect element for the added filed

```
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="drug" class="form-label">Medicine </label>
              <select name="drug[]" '="" class="form-control">NaN</select>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching just realized that the second way was supposed to work except that this `+  + data + "</select>" +` means I am using + as an addition operator and not a concatenator, changing it to `+ data + "</select>" +` solved my problem. I do not still understand what the issue could have been with the first approach